# Tomcat working directory for Java Web Start applications?

Tags: java, tomcat

My application folder inside the Tomcat webapps folder contains a .jnlp, .jar and .html that reference each other properly. My .jar file accesses external resources, for example my code reads:

```
fileWriter = new FileWriter("In.csv");
```

However, when I run the app, it creates this In.csv file on my desktop instead! How do I change this working directory to the same folder as the .jar file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The working folder for a Tomcat servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584054/the-working-folder-for-a-tomcat-servlet)

Comment: Is the web start application writing file on Desktop through the .jar?

Comment: You can't. A JNLP application executes at the client, not at the server.

Comment: @ringbearer yes, it is writing the file through the .jar

Comment: @EJP so how does the client determine where to write the files?

Comment: See this discussion - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19710762/change-working-dir-in-java-webstart